# Parse error: syntax error in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home3/mathiasf/public_html/wp-content/themes/smartstart/functions/plugin-activation.php on line 991

this is what i found in line 991

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
```

How can I solve this error?

Here is the full code:  http://pastebin.com/UB0EWK2A

Comment: That normally means that the error occurs on an earlier line - can you add the block that occurs before line 991 to your question, please?

Comment: What are the previous lines?

Comment: The error means exactly what it says . . . it found an `if` when it wasn't expecting it.  Check the lines before . . . probably a forgotten semi-colon or closing bracket.

Comment: show us what is before this line !

Comment: Please do research before asking. There is [50 results for this error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Parse+error%3A+syntax+error%2C+unexpected+T_IF) already. We don't need a 51th. In addition, we expect you to put the code here. not on pastebin. however, throwing a wall of code at people and asking them to find a very trivial to fix error is off-topic for this site. For future questions, please consult http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Also, line 4 starts with a full stop, which will also produce a syntax error. I recommend you use a PHP IDE, such as NetBeans, which will highlight this for you in the editor itself.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot a `;` on the previous line, e.g.

```
echo 'foo'
if (...) { ... }
```

would trigger the error.

Comment: He's added a link to his code. You can remove the word 'probably' in your answer.