# Warning: require_once

Tags: php, wordpress

I forgot to renew my domain and I have finally done that, but no I get this error. What does this mean?

> `Warning: require_once(/home3/mathiasf/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/mathiasf/public_html/wp-content/themes/terra/functions/plugin-activation.php on line 989`
>
> `Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required ’/home3/mathiasf/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php’ (include_path=’.:/opt/php53/lib/php’) in /home3/mathiasf/public_html/wp-content/themes/terra/functions/plugin-activation.php on line 989`

Comment: The file '/home3/mathiasf/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' doesn't exist, as the error message states.

Comment: *Incompatibility of Theme/Plugin with your WordPress version?* Confirm the file exists physically first.

Comment: This is the second question in 30 minutes that doesn't meet our quality standards. Like [already explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751034/parse-error-syntax-error-in-wordpress#comment25882715_17751034) you want to familiarize yourself with the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice again. Note that you risk getting question banned and we don't want that to happen. In your own interest, take the time to read these posts please.

Comment: That file/path is correct, for the latest version of Wordpress. Try untarring a fresh copy of Wordpress in your domain root (public_html), you've probably just deleted part of WP.

Answer (score 2):

`/home3/mathiasf/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php` doesn't exists.

It says so there in the log, *No such file or directory*

Comment: but I searched cpanel and I found the file, so it does exist. But for some reason it tells me it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says, `'/home3/mathiasf/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php'` does not exist on your server.

Comment: I found the file and it was located in the exact folder where it says it was not found. This is why I am asking, because this confuses me. The file is there

Comment: You have a folder called home3 on your system?